# Indexerrror in Python

Tags: python, list, index-error

I am trying to webscrape a website for some information and the list contains 2500 links and when it comes to 741th element in the list or in other words when it comes to the 741th link it stops and I get this following error:

IndexError: list index out of range

And I don't get it because I can print the 741th element and it is a valid website, so why do I get this error?

I am new to coding and to this community and I am not impressed by the tone you all are writing in.

Comment: Also what happens if you do len(list) ? How many items does it return?

Comment: If you get the full error message, it will give you the line of code that generated the error.  This should give you the clue where the error happened.  Then add some coded just before that line, print the index you are using and the length of the array you are processing.  Somehow you know it's link index 741.  How do you know that?

Answer (score 1):

Then that clearly mean, you don't have `741th` element in your list! Your scraper is not returning 2500 links, it is only returning 740 links! For more information about `IndexError` you can visit [here](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/#indexerror). You haven't provided any code, so we can't solve your problem!

Try checking lenght of your list of doing `len(<list name>)`.

Comment: You are asking _why do I get this error_ so I have posted it as answer!